# Recover a corrupted database/tables

Tags: sql-server, corrupt-data

Our customer faces an issue with a corrupted database caused by a 3rd party software. Unfortunatelly they found out too late and no longer have a valid backup to return to. Fixing views etc. is easy but there are couple tables that are unaccessible and contain important data.

When trying to select data from corrupted tables I receive this error:

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
> pageid (expected 1:7733; actual 114:7667823). It occurred during a
> read of page (1:7733) in database ID 5 at offset 0x00000003c6a000 in
> file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\aspe_bad1.MDF'.  Additional
> messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide
> more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database
> integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database
> consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many
> factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Running `DBCC CHECKDB` gives this error

> Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a
> system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.

Running `DBCC CHECKTABLE` gives the same error as select does.

When running `DBCC PAGE` I get Metadata: ObjectId = 0, meaning:

> If you see the ObjectId is 0, that means there was no metadata found.
> This could be because:
>
> - The table that the page was part of has been deleted since the page    corruption was logged
> - The system catalogs are corrupt in some way
> - The page is corrupt and so incorrect values were used to look up the    metadata

Checking SQL Server Logs contains only 1 different error and that is:

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: unable to
> decrypt page due to missing DEK. Itoccurred during a read of page
> (1:7727) in database ID 5 at offset 0x00000003c5e000 in file
> 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\aspe_bad1.MDF'.  Additional
> messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide
> more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database
> integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database
> consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many
> factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Honestly I'm at my wits end. Can anyone help me fix this issue? Is it even possible to repair to at least some extent?

Thanks,
Z

Comment: It sounds like your best bet in this instance would be to open a Microsoft support ticket

Comment: A little old but still relevant [corruption blog entry](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/help-my-database-is-corrupt-now-what).

Comment: And it seems sql server 2008r2 is in use - which is completely unsupported now. Proper disaster recovery procedures are a hard lesson to learn - especially when using unsupported software.

Comment: Good spot yes 2008... forget MS support then. Trouble is, by still using something so old and out of support, most consultants also won't touch it.

Comment: See if you can somehow find at least a backup of the DEK

Comment: Unfortunately the corruption happened in November and they found out about the issue just a few days ago. Since they are keeping backups only a month old, there are no other backups. And as said, MS probably won't even talk to me since they are using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Bad news. My recommendation is to try to restore your latest backup onto another server and do a `dbcc checktable` first with the `REPAIR_REBUILD` option and, if that doesn't work, with `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`. That will hopefully get the table into a state where it can be queried at which point you salvage what you can to re-inject into your actual database. If you end up having to resort to `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` *assume you lost data*.

Comment: If it was encrypted with the missing DEK then I'm afraid you can kiss it goodbye, there is no way to get it back. But perhaps it's just the DB header pages which are corrupt. You may want to manually inspect the database boot page in a hex editor and see if you can track down what's happened

Comment: And I bet that they never attempted to restore any of the backups that they did have at any time.  A backup is useless unless you can actually restore it.  Poor DR planning and execution has unfortunately bit them.  @Charlieface - not 100% sure but wouldn't the boot page also be encrypted?

Comment: @BenThul sadly that does not work. All backups we tried return the error when running DBCC.

Comment: @Charlieface I can give it a try but with my expertise I'm not sure if I would be able to read HEX data.

Looks like the only solution is to use 3rd party SW to get the data back. I've tried demo version of SQL Recovery Tool and it actually returned 25 rows of the corrupted tables. Looks like someone will have to pay for the license though.

Comment: If it returned valid data then odds are good that TDE was *not* turned on. So it sounds like it's just an issue with the boot page or other metadata. Don't forget to run all recovery efforts on a copy of the current DB + logs, obviously.

Comment: @ZebRa - did you run the `dbcc checktable` commands on the restored copy?

Comment: @BenThul yes I did. Running it on SQL Server 2008. SQL 2014 or newer failed to restore the backup with nolock or something like that. Didn't really try to make it work since if I managed to fix it, there would be complications with compatibility when making a backup for the client.